# PyMongo and results from collection queries

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I'm trying to build a query (which in my mind should be super simple)
I'm coming from a strongly typed background, and the fact that the ide is clueless to help me is confusing.
I'm grabbing a result set, and using it in the next query. There is no .toString() option that it complains about.

```
#after copy, remove items from source
    def remove_from_source():
        ids = tempCollection.find({}, {"_id": 1})
        q = "{ _id: { $in: [" + ids + "] } }"
        x = sourceCollection.delete_many(q)
        print(x.deleted_count + "records deleted.")
```

What I get is...

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "Cursor") to str
```

But cursor has no string options...

**EDIT**
I'm now doing this, and it is still not working:

```
# after copy, remove items from source
def remove_from_source():
    ids_cursor = tempCollection.find({}, {"_id": 1})
    ids = ""
    for _id in ids_cursor:
        ids = ids + "ObjectId(" + str(_id['_id']) + "),"
    ids = ids.rstrip(',')
    q = "{ _id: { $in: [" + ids + "] } }"
    print(q)
    # x = sourceCollection.find(q)
    # print(x.count())
    # x = sourceCollection.delete_many(q)
    # print(x.deleted_count + "records deleted.")
```

If I take the output of q, and put it in a mongo query it works 100%
But PyMongo is not happy with this.
I can import bson ObjectId, but that will still not allow me to create q in a pymongo friendly manner.

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

Comment: maybe the str() function

Comment: The `find` method returns a _cursor_ - you can iterate the cursor, or apply other cursor methods to read data from it, like read to an array/list. So, the statement is showing the error: `q = "{ _id: { $in: [" + ids + "] } }"`

Comment: So I have to do this the RBAR way?
Row By Aggonizing row. (term coined by Jeff Moden from sqlservercentral)
Thanks @prasad_

Comment: RBAR, not necessarily. It depends upon what you want to do with your cursor data. Refer the [Cursor Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/)

Comment: Delete it. So it forms part of a process flow. Move half a million records into temp workspace. aggrigate them into new table, then delete from source the records in the temp work space, truncate temp, and copy the next half million for proccessing.

Comment: Just for reference: After q has been built up, it looks like this
{ _id: { $in: [ObjectId(6140ee248af8ccb1d649ccfa),ObjectId(6140ee248af8ccb1d649ccfb),ObjectId(6140ee248af8ccb1d649ccfc)...etc] } }

Answer (score 0):

ben,

I think you should create an array of object IDs first,

```
ids = [] 
for _id in ids_cursor:
    ids.append(_id['_id'])
```

then you can remove those items.

```
sourceCollection.delete_many({"_id": { "$in": ids }})
```

Comment: Is this javascript or python?
Will try and apply this method in python. Thanks.

Comment: @BenFourie sorry, you are right, I have a mistake in my answer, that was morning and I wasn't very focused.